# Accessing color variables in each component

Tags: vue.js, sass, frontend, nuxt.js

Im looking for a trick to make my life easier. I want to style each component in my nuxtjs application with a similar color palette, but I do need to enter the color palette in each component. Tried to use scss for the first time. How do I put variables more globally and how to reach them?

I tried to put the code into assets/scss/styles.scss But components know nothing, about remote scss.

$color1: #808060;

$color2: #3D3D34;

$color3: #151510;

$color4: #090906;

Comment: Read through this thread: (https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/328) particularly towards the end. It can tell you how to define some SCSS variables and have them globally available in your Vue components.

Answer (score 3):

As [@jayce444](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5496808/jayce444) mentioned, [this thread](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/328) will give you multiple options to achieve the task.

However, you need to think before you take this approach. In general, you should import your variables file in each component SCSS:

```
<style lang="scss">
    @import "<PATH_TO_ROOT>/assets/scss/styles.scss";

    .someclass { color: $some-variable; }
</style>
```

By doing this, you will protect yourself for many uncertain future possibilities. Some of them are:

- Splitting repository into multiple micro front-ends
- Moving into Lerna like Mono repo setup
- **Reusing component in other code-bases**

Being explicit is more maintainable than having magical auto/global imports. We, as developers, spend more time maintaining code than writing new code.

Alternately, another clean solution is not using `vue-loader` for managing SCSS. It means you should not use `style` tag inside `.vue` files.

Create one master `style.scss` file. For each component create dedicated `.scss` file. And import all these files into master `style.scss` like:

```
// External third party scss from node_modules
@import '~@material/button/button`;

// Base color style sheet (SCSS variable are global)
// By importing it here, all the subsequent .scss file have access to variables
@import './styles/colors`;

@import './components/component-1`;
@import './components/component-2`;

// .... Add remaining component
@import './components/component-n`;
```

There are a few advantages. Your stylesheet is no longer tied to the framework specific abstraction. You can reuse your style more easily with other code bases built on top of other frameworks. Of course, if you need to have **Scoped-CSS** which `.vue` files provide out-of-box, consider using BEM notation.

Finally, if you decide to import variables `.scss` file in each component, then you can use `node-sass` and `webpack` **aliases** to shorten the import path.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but the answer still might help someone.

So to include the variables, mixins any SCSS style globally you need to load it using [NuxtJS Style resource](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/style-resources).

So for example you would have the **settings.scss** file in /assets/scss

```
$color-one: #fff;
$color-two: #000;
```

And you would import it in **nuxt.config.js** through styleResources object

```
styleResources: {
    scss: ['assets/scss/settings.scss']
},
```

Make sure to read the [Style Resources documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/style-resources) for more info